# How do I limit the parameter types of a generic argument based on another parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, types, enumeration

I'm trying to create a map of different configurations, where each configuration has a given key object and some options, e.g.

- `FirstConfig` can be either:

  - `FirstConfigOptionA`
  - `FirstConfigOptionB`
- `SecondConfig` can be either:

  - `SecondConfigOptionA`
  - `SecondConfigOptionB`
- ...

And I'm having trouble with general typing and signature of the setter function so it checks at compile time I'm supplying the correct objects, e.g.

```scala
// 1. this should compile normally
set(FirstConfig, FirstConfigOptionA)

// 2. should NOT compile due to `SecondConfigOptionA` parameter not being a valid option for `FirstConfig`
set(FirstConfig, SecondConfigOptionA)
```

So far, my attempts still allow the second case above to compile.

```scala
abstract sealed class Configuration
trait OptionKey[T <: Configuration] {}
trait OptionVariant[T <: Configuration] {}

// First Config
trait FirstConfig extends Configuration
object FirstConfigKey extends OptionKey[FirstConfig];
object FirstConfigOptionA extends OptionVariant[FirstConfig]
object FirstConfigOptionB extends OptionVariant[FirstConfig]

// Second Config
trait SecondConfig extends Configuration
object SecondConfigKey extends OptionKey[SecondConfig];
object SecondConfigOptionA extends OptionVariant[SecondConfig]
object SecondConfigOptionB extends OptionVariant[SecondConfig]

def set[T](k: OptionKey[T], v: OptionVariant[T]): Unit = {}

set(FirstConfigKey, FirstConfigOptionA)
set(FirstConfigKey, SecondConfigOptionA) // This still compiles
```

I've also tried using Enumerations with similar results:

```scala
object FirstConfig extends Enumeration {
  type FirstConfig = Value
  val FirstConfigOptionA, FirstConfigOptionB = Value
}

object SecondConfig extends Enumeration {
  type SecondConfig = Value
  val SecondConfigOptionA, SecondConfigOptionB = Value
}

def set(k: Enumeration, v: Enumeration#Value): Unit = {}

set(FirstConfig, FirstConfig.FirstConfigOptionA)
set(FirstConfig, SecondConfig.SecondConfigOptionA) // This still compiles
```

What is the correct way to express this relationship between a config and its available options or what should be `set`'s signature to enforce it?

Comment: Can you try option like this for first case?
`def set[T <: Configuration](k: OptionKey[T], v: OptionVariant[T]): Unit = {}`

Comment: No, that didn't work for me. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using path-dependant types like this:

```scala
trait Configuration {
  sealed trait OptionKey
  val key: OptionKey
  
  sealed trait OptionVariant
}

object Configuration {
  def set(config: Configuration)(variant: config.OptionVariant): Unit = {
    println(s"${config} - ${config.key} - ${variant}")
  }
}

case object FirstConfig extends Configuration {
  private case object FirstConfigKey extends OptionKey
  override final val key: OptionKey = FirstConfigKey
  
  case object FirstConfigOptionA extends OptionVariant
  case object FirstConfigOptionB extends OptionVariant
}

case object SecondConfig extends Configuration {
  private case object SecondConfigKey extends OptionKey
  override final val key: OptionKey = SecondConfigKey
  
  case object SecondConfigOptionA extends OptionVariant
  case object SecondConfigOptionB extends OptionVariant
}
```

---

*You can see it working as expected [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/aWrzeEuuTMSw1kyRi5TZCA/3)*.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to store them as key/value pairs? You can just represent it as an algebraic data type:

```scala
enum FirstConfig:
  case OptionA
  case OptionB

enum SecondConfig:
  case OptionA
  case OptionB

enum Config:
  case First(value: FirstConfig)
  case Second(value: SecondConfig)

def set(config: Config): Unit = …
```

Comment: Please don't use Scala 3 syntax when answering a question that does not have the `scala-3` tag.

Comment: Dude, I’m not wasting my time writing ADTs in Scala 2 syntax anymore.

Comment: But happy to waste other people's time when they try this and it doesn't work? Nice.

Comment: We’ll have to agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: fwiw, I'm using Scala 2. In any case, thanks for the answer, being overall new to Scala it's good to know this is available in newer versions.